# calculate gpa oracle pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a noobie in pl/sql. I am trying t calculate gpa using pl sql. i have created a table with grades with values in it.

```
SSN             CNO           GRADE
--------------- -------- ----------
55555           cs101             1
55555           math101           4
55555           bio101            1
55555           cgdd101           3
55555           swe203            3
55555           eng101            3
11111           bio101            4
11111           cgdd101           4
55555           cs101             1
55555           math101           4
55555           bio101            1
```

I am trying to calculate gpa with the following pl sql function but I get the following error.

```
55555           eng101            3

36 rows selected.

SQL> create or replace function get_count
  2  return is
  3  declare
  4  v_count number;
  5  begin
  6  select count(*) into v_count from grade;
  7  return grade;
  8
  9  end;
 10  /

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION GET_COUNT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/8      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the
         following:
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> self
         long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
         national character nchar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is missing a return data type, e.g.:

```
create or replace function get_count
return NUMBER is
v_count number;
...
```

Also, you don't need the `declare`.

Comment: And it should be `return v_count;` instead of `return grade;`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_COUNT
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   V_COUNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO V_COUNT
     FROM GRADE;
   RETURN V_COUNT;
END;
```

Comment: Quick question. When do I know when to use declare? Is it in a procedure?

Comment: `DECLARE` is used to start an anonymous block in PL/SQL if the block needs any local declarations (e.g. variables). It is not needed for a procedure, function or package because the declaration section is implied before the `BEGIN`.